# Docker compose Redis ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, redis

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Shouldn't running
`docker-compose up` create the containers in one network by default? I have no problems connecting if I just run the server in localhost, only when I create an image of the app in docker.

yaml file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:14.2-alpine
    container_name: postgres_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - staging.env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes: 
      - postgres-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis_cache:
    image: redis:6.2.6-alpine
    container_name: redis_cache
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: redis-server
    volumes: 
      - redis-vol:/data
  email_ms:
    build:
      context: ./
    container_name: email_ms
    image: email-ms
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
      - redis_cache
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    env_file:
      - staging.env
volumes:
  postgres-vol:
  redis-vol:
```

server.ts

```
   const redis = require("redis");
   export const redisClient = redis.createClient({ host: "redis_cache" });

   (async () => {
     redisClient.on("error", (err: any) => console.log("Redis Client Error", err));
     redisClient.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("connected to Redis");
      });
     await redisClient.connect();
   })
```

Error:

```
  | Redis Client Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
  |   errno: -111,
  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  |   syscall: 'connect',
  |   address: '127.0.0.1',
  |   port: 6379
  | }
```

EDIT: I removed the volume for email-ms

And this is my `docker ps`
[image]

They are all on the same network.

[image]

I'm running Docker using Windows WSL2. Not sure why it's still trying to connect to localhost.

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379` makes me think it's trying to connect to localhost and not redis_cache. Try running `docker-compose build` to make sure the image is up to date.

Comment: @HansKilian I removed the container and images then ran `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up` but same error.

Comment: Did it _ever_ say `127.0.0.1`?  The `volumes: [email-ms: /src]` block has pretty much no effect other than to cause Docker to ignore changes in your image, and you can remove that line and the corresponding volume declaration at the bottom of the file.

Comment: is `server.ts` part of your docker compose? only services in the network will be able to refer to one another by their service names, ie `postgres_db`, `redis_cache`, `email_ms`. btw you don't need to specify ports for inter-service communication on the same network.

Comment: @よつば Yes, server.ts is email_ms. It seems more likely a Windows problem, maybe.